# How to take an image from user and display it inside a CardView like Google Keep?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-cardview

#### Presently I am using a card view :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="1dp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
            android:id="@+id/person_photo"
            android:src="@drawable/nature"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/person_name"
            android:layout_below="@+id/person_photo"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:text="THE TITLE"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/person_age"
            android:layout_below="@+id/person_name"
            android:text="Then the text"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and feeding it data from an **ArrayList** which pulls data from an SQLite Database, I want to know how can I let the user choose his/her own image for any particular **cardview** ?

Comment: Please elaborate your question in more detail. From where you want to user select the image?

Comment: @BhawnaRaheja I have a form like activity which allows users to enter data (via EditText fields). I am able to show the user entered text data inside the cardview by feeding the values of the database to an ArrayList. I am only able to set the image of a card, if I can feed the image path as "R.drawable.image". How can I let user choose (from the form activity) its own image from phone gallery and get its path in somewhat like "R.folder.image" ?

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter class set an onclicklistener for the cardview